# Ejecución por perfil maven

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, appium

buenas a tod@s, estoy intentando lanzar por perfil maven, quiero hacer un getProperty para leer el POM, solo vale con esa propiedad, esta la parte donde llamo al getProperty, que siempre me llega null:

```
        @Override
        @Before
        public void setUp() throws Exception {  
            String deviceType = System.getProperty("platform");
        
            System.out.println("Valor de device.type: " + deviceType);
              System.out.println("System property: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
              System.out.println("Operating System: " + System.getProperty("os.name"));
              System.out.println("Java runtime version: " + System.getProperty("java.runtime.version" ));
                
              if (getPlatform().equalsIgnoreCase("android")) {
                  androidDriver = connectAppiumAndroid();
               } else if (getPlatformIos().equalsIgnoreCase("ios")) {
                   iosDriver = connectAppiumIos();
               } else {
                   throw new Exception("Plataforma no compatible");
               }
       
              try {
                
                  androidDriver = connectAppiumAndroid();
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Manejar la excepción cuando no se encuentra una plataforma compatible
                    System.out.println("ejecutamos ios: ");
                 
                    iosDriver = connectAppiumIos();
                }

        }
```

Aquí es donde llamo si es android o no, pero quería que lo hiciera por perfiles maven, para usar el getProperty

```
// Método para obtener la plataforma con la que trabajará
            private String getPlatform() {
                // Lógica para determinar la plataforma (Android o iOS)
                // Por ejemplo, podrías usar una variable de entorno o un argumento para indicar la plataforma
                return "android"; // Cambia esto para obtener la plataforma real
            }
            
            private String getPlatformIos() {
                 return "ios";
            }
```

Aquí donde llamo en mi perfil maven:

```
 <profile>
    <id>android-test</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <groups>calculadora</groups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Definir la propiedad 'platform' para el plugin -->
                    <properties>
                        <platform>android</platform>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Al ejecutar con maven: mvn test -Pandroid-test. Me lo hace bien, pero me llega null en el getProperty, parece que no me reconoce mi POM.xml. Me falta algo más? Estoy con java 1.18 y maven 3.8.4. Es por la dependencia de maven que debe ir otra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, debemos añadir testNG para poder ejecutar con el system.Property. El junit no permite leer datos del POM de getPorperty.

1. añadir plugin testng en nuestra herramienta
2. añadir al proyecto el plugin de testng